# Comparison behavior of ' <' operator

Tags: c++, string

Why is this printing "Popescu" instead of "Ionescu", since "Popescu" > "Ionescu"?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char v[3][100] = {"Popescu","Ionescu","Vasilescu"};
    if(v[0]<v[1]){
        cout << v[0];
    }else{
        cout << v[1];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `strcmp`, now you compare values of pointers, not content of strings.

Comment: ..or use `std::string` which has an `operator<` that does what you expect

Comment: it's not really about what to use in order to make it make any sense, I'm just curious why is it happening when i use <

Comment: @EuLaurD memory location pointer comparison is happening here. "Popescu" memory pointer is less than "Ionescu". So the actual pointer value is not compared.

Comment: `v[0] < v[1]` compares the addresses of the (first character) of the strings.  Since `"Popescu"` is before `"Ionescu"`, it has a lower address.    Use `strcmp()` if you actually want to compare the content of the strings.

Comment: @EuLaurD see my answer better understand how char and string work with 2d array and 1d array

Answer (score 5):

Since `char[100]` doesn't have an `operator<`, you fall back to `operator<` for `char*`. That was not what you intended - it returns the first object in memory. And `v[0]` definitely precedes `v[1]`.

You want `std::string`, where `operator<` is overloaded to do what you want.

Comment: not sure, but isnt it even the case that OP was lucky that both pointers point to elements in the same array, because otherwise comparing the pointers would be UB?

Comment: @idclev463035818: Indeed, that is relevant. If you had two independent `char[100]` objects, you wouldn't be allowed to compare their pointers with `<`, you'd need `std::less<char*>`.

Comment: Not even sure it is not already UB, as we don't compare `char (*)[100]` (as `&v[0] < &v[1]` would do).

Comment: @Jarod42 - comparing addresses that are within the same object (in this case, elements of the same multi-dimensional array) is well defined.

Comment: @MSalters I m trying above programme I think ```EuLaur D```  confuse with array position that is why confused.

Answer (score 1):

Your Initialization is wrong that is why print 'Popescu'

**First You need to clear about your array position that is main criteria before start work on your program see my image**

see below example:

char always take one character:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char v[3][3] =
    {
     {'p','I','l'},
     {'s','e','r'},
     {'q','w','x'}
    };

    cout<< v[0][0];  //print the array2d 

    return 0;
}
```

output:

**p**

First Condition:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char v[3][100] = {"p","I","l"};    

    if(v[0][0]==v[0][0])
    {
        //cout << v[0]; //when uncomment this line output is p
        cout << v[1];  **see here print the i because check the position of array image**
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << v[1];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**output: I** //now the position of your array see below

[image]

Now the second Condition:

```
int main(){

    char v[3][100] = {"p","I","l"};    

    if(v[1]==v[1])
    {
        // cout << v[0];
        cout << v[1];   
    }
    else
    {
        cout << v[1];
    }
    return 0;
```

output:
**I**

If the above criteria Understood then Come To your main problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char v[3][100] = {"p","I","l"};    

    if(v[0]<=v[1])
    {
        cout << v[0];
        // cout << v[2];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << v[1];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**output: p**

I hope my answer is understood.

Comment: @EuLaur D all confusion clear where try my program and remember that position of 2darray